# How to pass built in or custom functions as attributes in another function's definition in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, higher-order-functions

For instance, pseudo code: (if anyone can convert my pseudo code to actual code i may understand better, Thanks)

```
def check(s,function):
    return s.function

#calling method
a = check('stackoverflow',.isalpha())
b = check('hello World', .isdigit())
```

I believe functions are objects in python, so how do I refer to them. FYI `isalpha()` is a built in function in python.

```
syntax: 'variable = String.isalpha()
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `check` to an actual application of the function ont he argument:

```
def check(s, function):
    return function(s)
```

When calling, refer to the function but do not call it (drop the parenthesis):

```
check('stackoverflow', str.isalpha)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right, functions are objects in Python. Defining a function with `def` creates a function object and assigns it to the name in `def` statement. So you can reassign functions to different names, store in lists and dictionaries, pass over to other program objects, etc. - all refering to the function by its name. To execute a function when needed use `()`, after the name refering to the function. In Python there're also other objects, that are 'callable', like functions, - objects which implement special `__call__` method and therefore could be invoked using `()`.

In your code it is a little unclear what you try to achieve, so I'll just show you a few uses...

E.g. `isalpha()` is an attribute of string, so you could issue it directly:

```
"Hello world!".isalpha()
```

or in another function:

```
check_isalpha(s):
    return s.isalpha()

a = check_isalpha('Hello world!')
```

Since it's an attribute, you can get it using it's name as a string:

```
def check(s, func_name):
    try:
        return getattr(s, func_name)()
    except AttributeError:
        return None

a = check('Hellow world!','isalpha')
b = check('Hellow world!', 'isdigit')
```

or define custom function and pass it to another function:

```
def check(s, func):
    return func(s)

def custom_check(i):
    return i > 0

a = check(10, custom_check)
```